# Role-based security on DLL

Tags: .net, code-access-security

Help!  What's wrong with this code?  I've got a Windows Forms app where I need to protect a DLL using role-based security; only someone in a "MyRole" can make calls to this assembly.

I've tried two different methods for setting the current principal, but all I get is "Request for principal permission failed."

Here's a small console app demonstrating the problem.  Thanks in advance!

```
Imports System.Security

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Try
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(Principal.PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal)

            'Dim oCurrPrincipal As New Principal.WindowsPrincipal(Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
            'Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = oCurrPrincipal

            Dim oWriter As New Writer
            oWriter.WriteLog("It seems so simple, why doesn't it work?")

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            Console.ReadLine()
        End Try

    End Sub

End Module

Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports System.Security

<PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role:="MyRole")> _
Public Class Writer

    Public Overloads Sub WriteLog(ByVal sMessage As String)
        Console.WriteLine(sMessage)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a principal that is actully in the MyRole role?  Your current code will cause a WindowsPrincipal to be uses, and that principal's roles will corresponding to the user's Windows/domain groups, which presumably do not include "MyRole".  If you're not sure how to test this using a principal in the target role, try the following instead of your `SetPrincipalPolicy` call:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(New GenericPrincipal(New GenericIdentity("somebody"), New String() { "MyRole" }))
```